# MongoDB react app working locally not in heroku

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, heroku

I am trying to deploy a react site with Heroku everything is working except the data from my MongoDB Atlas is not sending to Heroku. The app is working as it should locally, I have tried everything I have seen on the help section and I am not sure what to do next.

[This is where I connect the MongoURI to the heroku app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t8qB.png)

[This is where the cluster is shown it is connected in Heroku tails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A08hu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently you cannot connect to your cluster from a non-whitelisted IP i.e. your Heroku's server IP. To test this - if you have a test env or the project doesn't have any data in it yet, you can open up your cluster to the world, check that the data is being pulled and then enable white-listing and add your server's IP. For maximum security you don'y want to open up your cluster to all connections, instead just add you IP.

Refer to the screen attached. In Atlas panel, go to your cluster, Network Access and click `ADD IP ADDRESS`. This might look a bit different for you if there are no address there yet - then follow the config wizard.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding I forgot to mention I have whitelisted my network and it is still not giving any data

Comment: What does your network consist of? Heroku service would be something outside your network by default and hosted on their remote cloud infrastructure.

Comment: I have the network access at 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: That's good. You'll find the issue, no doubt. First, could you clarify your solution architecture (e.g. react frontend deployed to Netlify, nodejs backend deployed to heroku and mongodb atlas database)? Is your React frontend deployed somewhere as well?

Comment: My react front end, node.js and mongodb all are deployed through heroku

Comment: Ok, few things worth checking. Is your node app able to correctly read the MONGO_URI env var (does it console.log actual connection string)? If not, check dotenv (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). If yes, use Postman or Insomnia to check your app's endpoint. If you get a status code other than 200, check heroku logs for error logs. In case of 200 status, backend is not at fault. Does React app swap out endpoint URLs for backend's heroku addresses (e.g https://stormy-retreat-84548.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users)? If any of these are the issue I can share some nice patterns to deal with them.